# Compiling NodeJS for PPC Architecture

Tags: node.js, powerpc

I am trying to compile NodeJS for PPC architecture but It fails with **"cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option -std=gnu++0x"**. From analysis I infer my Executable didn't support c++0x standard for compilation.Kindly suggest any other alternative way that i can use to compile Nodejs.

Comment: Hi! We may need a few more details in order to answer your question. Can you include the steps you took to get this error? And the versions of NodeJS, and the build tools that you're using?

Comment: Hai Jeremy, We have exported the CC and CXX variable with our own GCC(version 3.4.3) and G++ (version 3.4.3) compilers and trying to build the NodeJS.  NodeJS version : v8.11.3(We have tried in 4.x also)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your compiler predates the C++11 standards (`-std=gnu++0x` is an alias for `std=gnu++11`). From gcc's [c++ version status](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) page:

> GCC 4.8.1 was the first feature-complete implementation of the 2011 C++ standard, previously known as C++0x.

Can you use a newer compiler that supports the C++ standard required by nodejs?

Comment: Hai Jeremy, Thanks for your support. Based on our discussion with corresponding team the upgradation of C/C++ is not possible now. So we are searching for C/C++ binaries for PPC 32 bit, so that we can build with those binaries.Kindly suggest any other alternatives if you know.Thanks.

Comment: By "upgradation of C/C++ is not possible", do you mean you can't update the language standards version of an existing codebase? Or that you're not willing to use a new version of the compiler? Keep in mind that new compilers will still support older C/C++ standards.

Comment: Hi Jeremy ,At the moment we are not able to update the new version of the compiler. Because PPC is not widely used here.So the team considering this request as low priority.